# Deploy a java application from Linux on EC2 instance

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have used SSH to transfer a java project from linux to ec2 instance in .rar format , How can i ensure that the code is correctly deployed on the ec2 instance ? 
Are there any changes in ec2 dashboard that indicate the deployment ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WinSCP software to transfer files between your local machine and remote machine. You need to [download](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) and install WinSCP into your local machine. Login to your remote machine through WinSCP.

You have two tabs. Left tab is your local machine and right tab is remote machine. You can just transfer files from local to remote. You comes to know where you can store your files in remote machine.

From EC2 dashboard, you can get connection details to SSH into an EC2 instance. It will not indicate any deployment in EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is not anything in the EC2 dashboard that would indicate that you had deployed your Java application successfully. The EC2 dashboard only indicates the general state of your EC2 server resources, it does not indicate what software you have installed and running on those EC2 servers.

An EC2 instance is just a server. You would need to SSH into the server and actually run your application somehow. Just copying a .rar file to an EC2 server doesn't deploy your application. Everything you would have to do to deploy your application to a local Linux server you would also need to do in order to deploy your application to your EC2 Linux server.